# How to find the supremum of the sequence $(x_n)$, where $x_n = \frac{2n}{6n+3}$ without using any calculus.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

My professor gets upset when we use Calculus to solve problems in his Introduction to Abstract Math course. I have taken Linear Algebra, Discrete Math, and Calculus I.

I have no idea how to find the supremum of the sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n = \frac{2n}{6n+3}$ for $n \geq 1$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ without using a limit. I know that the limit of $x_n$ as $n$ approaches infinity is $\frac{1}{3}$, which would be the supremum, but I do not know how to show that without doing a limit. How would I go about finding that?

Comment: $x_n=\dfrac13-\dfrac1{6n+3}$

Comment: Also, $x_n = {2 \over 6 + {3 \over n}}$.

Comment: Wouldn't these still use limits to solve them though? My professor said to not use limits because we are not taking calculus.

Comment: Why not use substitution ? (Not all values, but a few as to decide how the sequence goes; you may end up with a proper solution)

Comment: Could I "arbitrarily" pick $\frac{1}{3}$ and prove that it is greater than or equal to all $x_n$ by induction or something like that?

Comment: I have no idea... I am just 15 years old .

Comment: @Spectre you can't just substitute values in because just because it may hold for the millionth term doesn't mean it holds for the billionth term, for example, even though you could intuitively get an idea of what it is.

Comment: But the sequence seems to shrink... which grows faster ? $2n$ or $6n + 3$ ? The later is what grows faster obviously. I used this intuition to say that substituting just a  few values would suffice.

Comment: I agree in part to that, however intuition alone isn't strong enough if you want to prove something. It's just not rigorous, and what is intuitive to someone may not be intuitive to everyone.

Comment: Wait... the thing is not shrinking ! Sorry....

Comment: Possibly $x_n$ would be greater for a greater $n$, then ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113148/discussion-between-calypso-rivers-and-spectre).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The transformations suggested above , need not be followed by a limit argument.

Indeed, from $a_n = \frac 13 - \frac{1}{6n+3}$, it is clear that $\frac 13$ is an upper bound. To see that no smaller number is an upper bound, simply consider $\frac 13 - \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$, and  we want to show that this is not an upper bound.

For this, we need an $N$ such that $a_n > \frac 13 - \epsilon$, which translates to $\frac 13 - \frac 1{6n+3} > \frac 13 -\epsilon$, which is equivalent to $\frac 1{6n+3} < \epsilon$, which becomes $6n+3 > \frac 1\epsilon$, and finally $n > \frac {1}{6 \epsilon} - \frac 12$.

Now note that if $N  = \left\lceil \frac 1{6 \epsilon} - \frac 12\right \rceil + 1$ (we do ceil because we need to make $N$ an integer. Furthermore, if $\frac 1{6 \epsilon} - \frac 12$ was already an integer, then this ceil doesn't give us a strictly bigger quantity than it, so we add $1$) then $N > \frac {1}{6 \epsilon} - \frac 12$ , so $a_N > \frac 13 - \epsilon$, therefore $\frac 13 - \epsilon$ cannot be an upper bound.

We may have mimicked what we do in a limit argument, but nowhere was the word limit used.

---

The reason for picking $\frac 13$ as a candidate supremum though, certainly required limit-type intuition, because you have to anticipate that the fraction $\frac 1{6n+3}$ gets closer to $0$ as $n$ increases, which means that $a_n$ gets closer to $\frac 13$.

But it is not possible to solve this problem unless you have a candidate for the supremum, and you can't get a candidate for the supremum without studying what happens to $a_n$ for large $n$, which is like studying the limit.

Therefore, you cannot avoid the entire limit-type approach if you want to solve this problem , the above rephrasing is the best you can do.

Comment: I'm confused as to how you got to the part with the floor function. Where did that come from?

Comment: As it's unable to let me edit - I meant to say ceiling function.

Comment: @CalypsoRivers Understood, I will edit.

Comment: @CalypsoRivers Edit complete, you can have a look.